# count number of records in a table with in once

Tags: sql, sql-server

are there any way to count the record in a table with only one query and many conditions, the conditions will overlap together like this

```sql
select @count1 = count(1) from table_name where condition1
select @count2 = count(1) from table_name where condition1 and condition2
select @count3 = count(1) from table_name where condition1 and condition2 and condition3
select @count4 = count(1) from table_name where condition1 and condition2 and condition3 and condition4
```

I want to get all @count1, @count2, @count3, @count4 in just one time query to table_name because the data in this table contains millions of records

Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: You could use a CASE for each of the conditions - in the CASE statements, output a 1 (if the condition is met) or 0 (if not met), and SUM each of those cases

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: this question is being asked about all sql database in general, but my issue occured in sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I mean in my comment - using CASE statements (and SUMming) to get your desired results

```
SELECT
    @count1 = SUM(CASE WHEN condition1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    @count2 = SUM(CASE WHEN condition1 AND condition2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    etc. ...
FROM table_name
```

Comment: thanks, it works. I didn't think it's simple like this